# Combining a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I'm trying to create a voting style system where the user selects 2 numbers from 2 separate groups of radio buttons.

I've been able to do this, however I don't feel it's as optimised as it should be:

**http://jsfiddle.net/f54wpLzg/11/**

```
function updateQuality() {
var quality = document.getElementsByClassName('quality');
for (var i = 0, length = quality.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (quality[i].checked) {
        totalQuality = parseInt(quality[i].value);
        break;
    }
}
qualityVal = totalQuality;    
document.getElementById('totalQuality').innerHTML = qualityVal;
}
```

Is there anyway to combine the functions? I'd prefer not to have the

> onclick="updateService();

On every single radio button as well...

Comment: you can do it in 1 line of js.. `$('input[type=radio]').on('click', updateService());` is this what you are looking for? this will bind the event to the click of ALL the radio buttons.

Answer (score 2):

You can both simplify and DRY up your code. Firstly add a `data` attribute to the containers to identify which element should be used to display the total:

```
<div id="quality" data-target="totalQuality">
    <input type="radio" class="quality" name="quality" value="1" />
    <input type="radio" class="quality" name="quality" value="2" />
    <input type="radio" class="quality" name="quality" value="3" />
</div>
<div id="service" data-target="totalService">
    <input type="radio" class="service" name="service" value="1" />
    <input type="radio" class="service" name="service" value="2" />
    <input type="radio" class="service" name="service" value="3" />
</div>

<br>

<span id="totalQuality">0</span>
<span id="totalService">0</span>
```

Then you can remove the `onclick` attribute and use jQuery to attach a single event handler to all the radios:

```
$('#quality input, #service input').change(function() {
    var total = $(this).parent().data('target');
    $('#' + total).html($(this).val());
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/f54wpLzg/14/)

Comment: I've ran into issues using data-* before in IE that's the thing. Is there any similar method? It's better than what I had originally either way so thank you :)

Comment: @potts what issues? I've used them a lot throughout my projects and never had any issues with IE

Comment: Some versions of Android have ignored data-* in the past and I've had problems with IE10 reading the data value. Could be an isolated incident though.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery you can remove the `onclick` attributes and do

```
$('#quality').on('change', '.quality', updateQuality);
$('#service').on('change', '.service', updateService);
```

in your script

---

To use a single method you could alter a bit your html to specify a target for each group (*to display the value*)

```
<div id="quality" data-target="#totalQuality">
    <input type="radio" class="quality" name="quality" value="1">
    <input type="radio" class="quality" name="quality" value="2" >
    <input type="radio" class="quality" name="quality" value="3">
</div>

<div id="service" data-target="#totalService">
    <input type="radio" class="service" name="service" value="1">
    <input type="radio" class="service" name="service" value="2">
    <input type="radio" class="service" name="service" value="3">
</div>
```

And then you can just do

```
function update() {
    var target = $(this).closest('[data-target]').data('target');
    $(target).text(this.value);
}

$('#quality, #service').on('change', 'input', update);
```

But it will not update global variables (*if you required those*)

Comment: But this will still require two separate functions would it not?

Comment: a yes.. i thought you just wanted to separate the javascript from the html..  will post an update

Answer (score 0):

you could just add a parameter inside the function then put a condition inside
something like this..

```
function updateVote(str) {
    var data = document.getElementsByClassName(str);
    for (var i = 0, length = data.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (data[i].checked) {
           totalCount = parseInt(data[i].value);
           break;
        }
    }
    val = totalCount; 
    if(str=="quality")
       document.getElementById('totalQuality').innerHTML = val;
    }
    else{
       document.getElementById('totalService').innerHTML = val;
    }
```

on your html file..

```
onclick="updateVote('service')"
```

or

```
onclick="updateVote('quality')"
```